# How to approach making a controller with (unlimited) db look-up routes

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm digging into ASP.NET MVC from classic asp, and have completed some tutorials. I understand the concept now, but I have a main question about the controller.  How are you able to control the url structure if you are getting your url's (with params) from a sql database?

Example: `/custom-url-1` or `/custom-url-23423411`
(Returns params accordingly to feed the code)

I'm guessing it would have to do with `ActionResult Index()` , but not sure where to go after that.  Any idea's where to look or is this even possible?  Does MVC even allow this?

Comment: Why would you store url's in a database, and what would `/custom-url-1` actually do?

Comment: @StephenMuecke with the concept of Asp.net MVC it would be `/custom-url/1` , but I would like to know how to make it `/custom-url-1` instead

Comment: @ZeeTee...you cannot make it as /custom-url-1 in mvc if you do in this way /custom-url-1 it will find a controller with name custom-url-1....

Comment: What can be done? Can a URL rewrite rule be written to another controller that handles these sub-requests? Like anything without a subdomain gets pointed to `/custom-controller/custom-url-1` or will there be conflicts in the normal routing?

Comment: Found it: http://www.kindblad.com/2011/04/search-engine-friendly-urls-in-aspnet.html

Comment: the same thing i was telling you in my below comments that you have to structure your database urls also according to mvc routing rules as showing in above link..thankz..@ZeeTee

Comment: What are you talking about, you had no answer.

Comment: Ok I misunderstood the last URL.  But as per this, it looks like I can do how I said using URL Rewrite and create a controller to handle it. http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/iis-url-rewriting-and-aspnet-routing

Comment: @ZeeTee...yes...above link might work for you...

Answer (score -1):

One Way you can approach this is to have everything go to one action in one controller and resolve the content in the view.
This is useful only if you have one type of view.

Second way is to have [route constraint](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-route-constraint-cs) or a [custom route constraint](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-custom-route-constraint-cs) for each type of content you have 
say : Galleries, Blog, Pages
and in each constraint check if the given url is of this type ( by db call), if the constraint returns true, it will point the request to the given controller and action.

The third way is to have a [custom route handler](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/380098/Basic-Routing-for-HttpHandler) that does the checking and routing (mind you this is probably the hardest task but works best if you have complex system, if your is simple try using method 1 or 2

P.S. if you want your urls separataed by "-" instead of "/" you can do just this

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "Default", // Route name
  "{controller}-{action}-{id}",// URL with parameters
  new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" } // Parameter defaults
            );
```